# Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist

Tags: authentication, lumen

I am new to both laravel and lumen.
I was creating a login api with oauth2.0 in lumen 5.6, i have installed passport and generated token.
Below is my login controller function and it is working fine. It returns token.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use Auth;

public function login(Request $request)
        {
            global $app;    
            $proxy = Request::create(
                '/oauth/token',
                'post',
                [
                    'grant_type'    =>  env('API_GRAND_TYPE'),
                    'client_id'     =>  env('API_CLIENT_ID'),
                    'client_secret' =>  env('API_CLIENT_SECRET'),
                    'username'      =>  $request->username,
                    'password'      =>  $request->password,
                ]

            );
            return $app->dispatch($proxy);
        }
```

Since i have to check user status apart from username and password, i need to check the user credential first. so i do like this.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return ['result' => 'ok'];
    }

    return ['result' => 'not ok'];
}

Here i am getting this error.
Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.

So i tried Auth::check instead of Auth::attempt.
Now there is no error but it always return false even though the credentials are valid.

I searched a lot for a solution but i didn't get.
```

Comment: any solution...?

Answer (score 20):

The function guard is only available for routes with web middleware

```
public function login() {

  if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], false, false)) {requests
     // good
  } else {
    // invalid credentials, act accordingly
 }
}
```

Comment: the problem is package functions like spatie/laravel-permission work on api so i think we should use mix of api and web for RESTFUL applications

Comment: Note: When using the @Samuel Dervis solution do not forget to remove your login route from: `'middleware' => 'auth: api'`, if it's inside.

The guard method also accepts the api parameter, as `Auth::guard('api')` but I currently encounter difficults when using it.

Comment: In my case, my controller class was named `Auth`. So I had to create an alias for the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`.

Comment: life saver thanks, I just created a new method with this to avoid damaging the api auth method I'm currently using, and worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Changing default guard to "web" fixed my problem.

> config/auth.php:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

Comment: This will be a problem when using multiple guards and a package laravel spatie for permission management.

Answer (score 1):

using jwt it's worked for me

1-Auth::attempt($credentials)

just replace line 1 to line 2

2-$token = Auth::guard('api')->attempt($credentials)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct, 'Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard' does not in fact have any method called 'attempt()', as seen in the official documentation: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Auth/RequestGuard.html.

This is a confusion with 'Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard', this has the 'attempt()' method and is what you should be using, see: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html

However, the good news is that you will still be able to log in using Auth() because RequestGuard has two other methods that do the same job as 'attempt()', try something like this:

```
Route::post('/login', function (Request $request) {

    $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
    ]);
 
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $password = $request->get('password');
    
    if(Auth::guard('enter_guard_name')->validate(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])){
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    Auth::guard('enter_guard_name')->setUser($user);

    return Auth::guard('enter_guard_name')->User();
    } else {
    return "Invalid credentials";
    }
});
```

The code above receives the user's credentials, which in this case is email and password, checks whether these credentials are correct and, if so, defines the user as logged in. One point of this approach is that you may not have session persistence. For cases where you need this persistence, be sure to use SessionGuard instead of RequestGuard.