# Laravel 5.6 Login Attempt Fails - Method RequestGuard::attempt does not exist is returned on Login Submit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I had implemented multi-auth for my application and it was working fine until it just stopped.I've scoured the internet for a solution but to no avail. So I do have  Admin Login Controller and the default Laravel Login controller which uses make:auth and implements authenticable for users. My admin login is working fine but the user login fails and returns this

```
BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.
```

The same thing happens when I try to register a user but this time it returns it returns

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::login does not exist.
```

Despite the error the user registration passes and the fields are actually populated in the users table from the registration form. Since I'm using the default auth I'm expecting it to automatically login , and i guess this is where the problem arises on the attemp method.

It's imperative to note that I am using Passport on the user Model for another module.

Below is how my Login Controller looks like

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

}
```

And my Admin Login Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'admin/dashboard';
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.admin-login');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the form data
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);
        // Attempt to log the user in
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }
        // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error', 'Invalid Access: Please Login With Your Credentials.');
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect('admin')->with('flash_message_error', 'Successfully Logged Out');;
    }

}
```

This is my guard  config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
        ],
    ],

];
```

And finally below is my user Model

```
namespace App;

use App\Modules\Event\Bookings;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use GrahamCampbell\Markdown\Facades\Markdown;

/**
 * @method static find($user_id)
 * @method static count()
 */
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'fname','lname', 'email','organization','phone_number', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',

    ];

    public function participant()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bookings::class);
    }


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Posts::class, 'author_id');
    }
    public function gravatar()
    {
        $email = $this->email;
        $default = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/User_icon-cp.svg/200px-User_icon-cp.svg.png";
        $size = 60;

        return "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ) . "?d=" . urlencode( $default ) . "&s=" . $size;
    }
        public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
    public function getBioHtmlAttribute()
    {
        return $this->bio ? Markdown::convertToHtml(e($this->bio)) : NULL ;

    }

}
```

Below is My Admin Model

```
namespace App;


use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

/**
 * @method static find($user_id)
 */
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',

    ];


}
```

I tried to use api as the default guard and it only worked temporarily and started to return the same error, I know attempt method only works on web middleware so what could be the problem? I've removed the vendor folder and reinstalled it using composer update still nothing.. just stuck.
Would immensly appraciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026557/method-illuminate-auth-requestguardattempt-does-not-exist)

Comment: Update your Admin Model instead of your User Model Cause you are going to Logged in from Admin Table

Comment: Need your Admin model for better understanding as you use Admin model for Authentication

Comment: Hi @sukel I've edited the post and added the admin model

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So to answer this question, after racking my brain, I decided to clear the application, configuration, and route caches,that did the trick for me.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

You can run the above statement in your console when you wish to clear the application cache. What it does is that this statement clears all caches inside storage\framework\cache.

```
php artisan route:cache
```

This clears your route cache. So if you have added a new route or have changed a route controller or action you can use this one to reload the same.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This will clear the caching of the env file and reload it

Finally you can run

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Composer dump-autoload won’t download a thing.
It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php).

Comment: Thank you so much :)